# regex get string before matched pattern

Tags: java, regex

I'm working on a project where i have to screen scrape a website and get a string. This is a part of the text.

> a href = "/dashboard/index/2971"
>   title="Project1:Project1">Project1

I need to get the "/dashboard/index/2971" part of the Whole Text using regex. Currently i have this:

```
 while(true){
                if (buff.readLine()!=null){
                    String wholeText = buff.readLine();
                    System.out.println(wholeText.contains("title=Project1"));
                    htmlCode += buff.readLine() + "\n";
                }else{
                    break;
                }
```

This just identifies the "title=Project1" String. I need to get the "/dashboard/index/2971" part and put it in a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$str = 'a href = "/dashboard/index/2971" title="Project1:Project1">Projeca...';

preg_match_all('#href\s*=\s*"(.*?)"#', $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

$foundURLs = array();
foreach ($matches as $match) {
    $foundURLs[] = $match[1]; 
}

var_dump($foundURLs);
```